# Not able to do a console.log in .then() after adding an object into firebase array

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, angularjs

I'm binding my firebase array to data variable and I'm adding an object into this array using $add but I'm unable to get an output from .then()

```
$scope.dbref =firebase.database().ref().child("Employee");  
     $scope.data = $firebaseArray( $scope.dbref);


var obj = {};
         obj.name=$scope.username;
         obj.age=$scope.age;
         obj.gender=$scope.gender;
         obj.active=$scope.active;
$scope.data.$add(obj).then(function(value){

  console.log('something');
  console.log(value.$id);

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry it was just that angular fire uses 3.6.6 and i was using 3.7.1